# adding alert condition in pine script

Tags: pine-script

I'm building my strategy for my trading bot using pine script.

Everything seems fine on the chart regarding the High Low signals.
But my issues are on the alerts.
I want to add alert for higherlow, higherHigh and LowerHign, LowerLow with different second.
I failed on trade because of that.

here is the screenshot: [image: https://i.gyazo.com/aac42461e28c3f13c7c149d5debfe228.png]
here is the code:

```
T0 = 'Zigzag values\nDefault : 14\nMin : 2\nMax : 50'
T1 = 'Short\nExample : L or LL\nLong\nExample : Low or Lower Low'
T2 = 'Constrast : Constrast color of chart background\nCustom : Input color\nNone : Color follow Trend Color'
T3 = 'Small font size recommended for mobile app or multiple layout'
T4 = 'Default\nStyle : Solid\nWidth : 4'
length       = input.int(            14,     'Length', minval = 2, maxval = 50, tooltip = T0)
colorUp      = input.color(color.lime,'Trend Color', inline = '0')
colorDn      = input.color( color.red,           '', inline = '0')
showLabel    = input.bool(         true,      'Label', group = 'Show / hide', inline = '1')
displayLabel = input.string(     'HHLL',       'Text', group = 'Label', inline = '2', options = ['HHLL', 'HL'])
nameHL       = input.string(    'Long',           '', group = 'Label', inline = '2', options = ['Short', 'Long'], tooltip = T1)
colorLabel   = input.string(    'Trend',      'Color', group = 'Label', inline = '3', options = ['Contrast', 'Custom', 'Trend'])
customLabel  = input.color(color.blue,           '', group = 'Label', inline = '3', tooltip = T2)
sizeLabel    = input.string(   'huge',       'Size', group = 'Label', inline = '4', options = ['tiny',  'small', 'normal', 'large', 'huge'], tooltip = T3)
lineType     = input.string(    'solid',    'Display', group =  'Line', inline = '5', options = ['dash', 'dot', 'solid', 'arrow right', 'arrow left'])
width        = input.int(             4,           '', group =  'Line', inline = '5', minval = 1, maxval = 4, tooltip = T4)
colorLine    = input.string(    'Trend',      'Color', group =  'Line', inline = '6', options = ['Contrast', 'Custom', 'Trend'])
customLine   = input.color(color.blue,           '', group =  'Line', inline = '6', tooltip = T2)
//#endregion

//#region ———————————————————— 1. Types
// @type        Used for label
// @field Hi    Float value of high
// @field Lo    Float value of low
type HL
    string      Hi = na
    string      Lo = na

// @type        Used for point especially for array
// @field x     int value for bar_index   
// @field y     float value for price
// @field sty   label style
// @field col   color for text label
// @field str   high or low string
type point
    int          x = na
    float        y = na
    string     sty = na
    color      col = na
    string     str = na

// @type          Used for initial setup
// @field hi      high value
// @field lo      low value
// @field colorHi color for high value
// @field colorLo color for low value
// @field strHi   string for high value
// @field strLo   string for low value
type startUp
    float       hi = na
    float       lo = na
    color  colorHi = na
    color  colorLo = na
    string   strHi = na
    string   strLo = na
//#endregion


//#region ———————————————————— 2. Switches
[H, L]            = switch nameHL
    'Short'       => [   'H',   'L']
    'Long'        => ['HIGH', 'LOW']
[Hi, Lo]          = switch nameHL
    'Short'       => [       'H',       'L']
    'Long'        => ['HIGHER\n', 'LOWER\n']
switchLine        = switch lineType
    'dash'        => line.style_dashed
    'dot'         => line.style_dotted
    'solid'       => line.style_solid
    'arrow right' => line.style_arrow_right
    'arrow left'  => line.style_arrow_left
switchLabelColor  = switch colorLabel
    'Contrast'    => chart.fg_color
    'Custom'      => customLabel
switchLineColor   = switch colorLine
    'Contrast'    => chart.fg_color
    'Custom'      => customLine
//#endregion

//#region ———————————————————— 3. Variables and arrays
float ph   = na,  ph := ta.highestbars(high, length) == 0 ? high : na
float pl   = na,  pl := ta.lowestbars(  low, length) == 0 ?  low : na  
var  dir   =  0, dir := ph and na(pl) ? 1 : pl and na(ph) ? -1 : dir
var zigzag = array.new<point>(0)
oldzigzag  = zigzag.copy()
dirchanged = ta.change(dir)
hiLo       = HL.new(Hi, Lo)
varSetup   = startUp.new(ph, pl, colorUp, colorDn, H, L)
//#endregion

//#region ———————————————————— 4. Custom Functions
// @function         variable for point
// @param   setup    type containing ternary conditional operator
// @returns newPoint to be used later in initialize
method dirVariables(startUp setup = na) =>
    var point newPoint = na 
    x   = bar_index
    y   = dir == 1 ?               setup.hi : setup.lo
    sty = dir == 1 ? label.style_label_down : label.style_label_up
    col = dir == 1 ?          setup.colorHi : setup.colorLo
    str = dir == 1 ?            setup.strHi : setup.strLo  
    newPoint  := point.new(x, y, sty, col, str)
    newPoint

// @function         initialize zigzag array
// @param   setup    type containing ternary conditional operator
// @param   maxSize  maximum array size
// @returns zigzag   array after cleanup
method initialize(point[] zigzag = na, startUp setup = na, int maxSize = 10)=>
    newPoint = setup.dirVariables()
    zigzag.unshift(newPoint)
    if zigzag.size() > maxSize
        zigzag.pop()

// @function         update zigzag array
// @param   setup    type containing ternary conditional operator
// @param   maxSize  maximum array size
// @param   dir      direction value
// @returns zigzag   array after cleanup   
method update(point[] zigzag = na, startUp setup = na, maxSize = 10, int dir = na)=>
    if array.size(zigzag) == 0
        zigzag.initialize(setup, maxSize)
    else
        newPoint = setup.dirVariables()
        dirOver = dir ==  1 and newPoint.y > zigzag.get(0).y
        dirLess = dir == -1 and newPoint.y < zigzag.get(0).y
        if dirOver or dirLess
            zigzag.set(0, newPoint)
        point.new(na, na, na, na, na)

// @function          compare zigzag
// @param   zigzag    original array
// @param   oldzigzag copied array
// @returns boolOr    Or statement
// @returns boolAnd   And statement  
method boolPoint(point[] zigzag = na, point[] oldzigzag = na, int offset = 0) =>
    boolOr = zigzag.get(offset + 0).x != oldzigzag.get(offset + 0).x  or zigzag.get(offset + 0).y != oldzigzag.get(offset + 0).y
    boolAnd = zigzag.get(offset + 1).x == oldzigzag.get(offset + 1).x and zigzag.get(offset + 1).y == oldzigzag.get(offset + 1).y
    [boolOr, boolAnd]

// @function         create label based on zigzag array
// @param   zigzag   original array
// @param   size     font size
// @param   offset   default value zero
// @returns          new label
method createLabel(point[] zigzag = na, string size = na, int offset = 0) =>
    label.new(   x         = int(zigzag.get(offset + 0).x),
                 y         =     zigzag.get(offset + 0).y,
                 text      =     zigzag.get(offset + 0).str,
                 xloc      =               xloc.bar_index,
                 color     = color.new(color.blue, 100),
                 style     =     zigzag.get(offset + 0).sty,
                 textcolor =     zigzag.get(offset + 0).col,
                 size      =                         size,
                 tooltip   =     zigzag.get(offset + 0).str + '\n' + str.tostring(zigzag.get(offset + 0).y)) 

// @function         create line based on zigzag array
// @param   zigzag   original array
// @param   width    line thickness
// @param   style    line style
// @param   offset   default value zero
// @returns          new line
method createLine(point[] zigzag = na, int width = na, string style = na, int offset = 0) =>
    line.new(x1    = int(zigzag.get(offset + 1).x),
             y1    =     zigzag.get(offset + 1).y,
             x2    = int(zigzag.get(offset + 0).x),
             y2    =     zigzag.get(offset + 0).y,
             xloc  =        xloc.bar_index,
             color =     zigzag.get(offset + 0).col,
             style = style,
             width = width)

// @function         create line based on zigzag array
// @param   zigzag   original array
// @param   hiLo     switch value
// @param   offset   default value zero
// @returns          ternary conditional of hiLo
method compareHL(point[] zigzag = na, HL hiLo = na, int offset = 0) =>
    dir ==   1 ? zigzag.get(offset + 0).y > zigzag.get(offset + 2).y ? hiLo.Hi : hiLo.Lo :
                 zigzag.get(offset + 0).y < zigzag.get(offset + 2).y ? hiLo.Lo : hiLo.Hi

// @function         set text and tooltip for label
// @param   this     original array
// @param   str      string value for text
// @param   tip      string value for tooltip
method textTip(label this = na, string str = na, string tip = na) =>
    this.set_text(   str)
    this.set_tooltip(tip)
//#endregion

//#region ———————————————————— 5. Execution
if ph or pl
    if dirchanged
        zigzag.initialize( varSetup, 4)
    else
        zigzag.update(varSetup, 4, dir)
//#endregion

//#region ———————————————————— 6. Constructs
if zigzag.size() >= 3
    var line   dirLine   = na
    var label  dirLabel  = na
    var string dirString = na
    [boolOr, boolAnd]    = zigzag.boolPoint(oldzigzag)
    if boolOr
        if boolAnd
            dirLine.delete()
            dirLabel.delete()
        if showLabel
            if displayLabel == 'HL' or displayLabel == 'HHLL'
                dirLabel := zigzag.createLabel(sizeLabel)
            if displayLabel == 'HHLL' and zigzag.size() >= 4                             
                dirString  := zigzag.compareHL(hiLo)
                dirLabel.textTip(dirString + zigzag.get(0).str, dirString + zigzag.get(0).str + '\n' + str.tostring(zigzag.get(0).y))
            if colorLabel != 'Trend'
                dirLabel.set_textcolor(switchLabelColor)
```

Comment: please hemp me guys. when any text like higher high higherlow etc will come then i want alert